# Kendo Grid Checkbox dirty flags are inconsistent

Tags: checkbox, kendo-ui, kendo-grid

I am having a issues with a checkbox column in a grid.

I have a grid with multiple checkbox columns. When I check the box, the dirty tick is not there, however when I click on the cell that contains the checkbox, but not the check box and then click the checkbox, I get the dirty tick mark.

Has anyone see this before? I would like it to be a bit more consistent because after a few clicks the dirty marks for some rows disappear.

This just seems odd.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Yes, I see this quite often: depends on how you implemented the checkboxes. If you tick directly a checkbox you modify the `input` but not the model. If you tick the cell and then the checkbox then Kendo UI toggle to edit mode and (in background) it replaces the checkbox with an *editable version* of the checkbox that is managed (event handler) by Kendo UI that allows to modify the model.

**EDIT:** If you want your checkbox always clickable then you might do:

```
var grid = $("#stocks_tbl").kendoGrid({
    dataSource: new kendo.data.DataSource({
        ...
        schema: {
            model: {
                id    : "id",
                fields: {
                    active: { type: "boolean" }
                }
            }
        }
    }),
    editable  : "incell",
    columns   : [
        {
            field   : "active",
            title   : "Active",
            template: '<input type="checkbox" data-bind="source: active" #= active ? checked="checked" : ""# />'
        },
        ...
    ]
}).data("kendoGrid");
```

Here, you define an `input` that is always clickable.

```
$(document).on("change", "[type='checkbox']", function(ev) {
    var item = grid.dataItem($(this).closest("tr"));
    item.set("active", ev.srcElement.checked);
});
```

with this, we define a handler for intercepting changes on the `input` and reflect them in the `model`.

This saves you having to play with `editable`

Comment: Hi, thanks for the info. You mentioned this all depends on how the checkbox is implemented. How else would you implement this? I want to force it to edit the model. The reason, I need to add a condition if the cell can be edited or not as well.

Comment: I've edited the post adding **EDIT** where I show how to manage clickable checkboxes in a grid always _editable_.

Comment: Thanks, would this work if I moved the binding of the change event in the databound. I have a combobox that controls the data populated in the grid.

Comment: It should work. Since we are binding it to `document` it should (actually) work for **any** `checkbox` (maybe you should consider narrowing it to something else making it faster)

Comment: I did narrow it down by giving a class to my checkbox. Since my grid has multiple checkbox columns. I associated a click event for each class.  The only thing now is in the click event, I need to set another column and that has issues retaining the dirty flag. Because it seems that when you call the .set method, it clears out the dirty flag class.

Comment: I cannot reproduce that question of _clearing out_ dirty flag. Check it here http://jsfiddle.net/OnaBai/rqPNH/. You will find two checkboxes, the first one I use the method above and when clicked it changes the content of the second one. With the second checkbox I do nothing so it does not affect neither the model nor the dirty flag. If you click on the `box` bellow the `grid` you will see a _dump_ of the grid data and if dirty is true it will show the text in red and background in yellow. If not dirty the text will be blue.

Comment: Sorry I must have misspoken. You're right the dirty property remained, however I was adding the dirty tick marks, the k-dirty-cell and the span for k-dirt. When the .set method was executed, the grid reloads. During this reload, the cell lost the dirty class. I fixed the issue but adding a couple of checks on my databound and readded that tick marks. Also, the other thing i didn't like, since I was making multiple .set calls, it reloaded the grid multiple times. So i set the property of the field instead... such as dataItem.x = y; and set the dirty property, then reload the grid once.

Answer (score 0):

Indeed first you need to click on the cell to enter 'edit' mode and then you can check/unched the actual checkbox. For better user experience you can implement your checkboxes just the same way they are implemented in [this code library article](http://www.kendoui.com/code-library/mvc/grid/checkbox-column-and-incell-editing.aspx). (If you are not using ASP.NET MVC wrappers - no worries just open the project go under **Views/Home/Index.cshtml** and you can copy/paste the code - it is all JavaScript.

The code library also includes how to create checkboxe 'Select all' in the column header.

Comment: I checked the project and it is mostly like what I have. There were a couple of differences. One is that I am setting my onClick event in my data bound because the data in my grid is driven off a combobox. I don't think this would be an issue. The other difference is instead of using a class, I was binding my click event to the input:checkbox. I changed it to the class, but still see the same isssue.

Answer (score 0):

The way I solved it was to make the fields in the model to be non-editable, so it forces the click event to fire and then I just update the values and set the dirty property. The thing was if you clicked the cell, the edit event was fired vs the click and vice versa, so instead of having two things fire, I just disabled one. Some would call it a hack, but I can't see how else to prevent both events from firing.

Answer (score 0):

Please try this one:

```
 //Cell click Checkbox select
    $('#grd' + gridName).on("click", "td", function (e) {
        var selectedTd = $(e.target).closest("td");              
         var grdChkBox = selectedTd.parents('tr').find("td:first").find('input:checkbox');
         grdChkBox.prop('checked', !grdChkBox.prop('checked'));

    });
```